# Global access to MemoryStream

Tags: .net, global-variables, memorystream

I want to serialize an object(Form) to the `MemoryStream` and ulteriorly be able to deserialize it.

Is it possible to keep (read and write into) a **global** "memoryStreamContainer" when application is running?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but please note that the `MemoryStream` is not thread-safe, so you'll need to serialize access to it, for instance, by using the lock statement.

Could could even write some sort of tread-safe wrapper, that could use any type of `Stream`:

```
public sealed class ThreadSafeStreamWrapper
{
    private readonly Stream wrappedStream;
    public ThreadSafeStreamWrapper(Stream wrappedStream)
    {
        this.wrappedStream = wrappedStream;
    }

    // implementation
 }
```

Comment: I agree that my question should be "How can I" :)